# Alien attack novel, a team of humans are sent on a suicide mission with every human on earth to direct them

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, alien-invasion

The book begins after Earth has been attacked several times, already. These alien vessels are being sent into the system and attacking the planet.

An elite team of humans from all over the world (iirc) called the “Angels” are sent up on what is almost always a suicide mission to stop the ship and prevent if from wreaking destruction on the planet. As I recall it, only one person has ever survived one of these and that person is in pretty bad shape. Their actions are guided by a crowdsourcing effort, where anyone on the planet can suggest an action, which I think were voted on before the Angels would carry them out.

The one I read was a paperback, I don't think it made it to hardback.

I read the book sometime between 2000 and 2010. It was in English and it was pretty new. It was an uncatalogued paperback from a library. I think the cover art was a space ship of some kind, but I'm not completely sure.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Could it be [Earthweb by Marc Stiegler](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Earthweb-Marc-Stiegler/dp/067157809X)?

I have the book, but it's in the (large) pile of books to be read one day so I'm going by some frenzied Googling and the Amazon summary:

> Someone Out There really hated humans. Twenty years ago Shiva I swept aside Earth's defenses and rained down destruction until a suicide squad boarded it and blew it to smithereens. Now Shiva V has entered the Solar System. Vastly more powerful than any of its predecessors, it has destroyed all fleets sent against it. There is only one way to defeat a Shiva: get inside and kill it. Once again, in the personae of five champions, four billion of us are about to do just that, linked and coordinated by -- The Earthweb!

The summary doesn't mention *The Angels*, but a quick skim through the book suggests that the group of champions sent to infiltrate Shiva are called *The Angels*.

Comment: Almost certainly it. The director being the only one to have ever survived (and minus his legs) and the military being seriously worried about his continued health is a big plot point -- because *no one other than him has managed to successfully direct a subsequent assault*.

Comment: Yes, this is it! I did mention the Angels, but it was just a passing mention. Thanks!